# _changed? method when using counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter-cache

I need to update attribute :average_rate when new comment is added. 
I have in comments.rb

```
  belongs_to :page, :counter_cache => true
```

and in page.rb

```
  has_many :comments
  after_save :update_average_rate
```

and update_average_rate method in page.rb

```
  def update_average_rate(comment)
    if comments_count_changed?
      write_attribute :average_rate, (comments.sum(:rate) / comments.count.to_f).ceil
    end
  end
```

but it doesnt work. When I am doing

```
raise comments_count_changed?.inspect
```

in update_average_rate method, it outputs "false" , but comments_count is changed. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `:before_save` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that counter updates don't actually set the "changed" flags to true.

For a column/attribute `a`, `a_changed?` will be true if and only if `a` has been changed but not saved to the database. [The basic behavior goes like this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html):

1. Load or create `o`. `o.a_changed?` will be false.
2. `o.a = pancakes`, `o.a_changed?` will be true.
3. `o.save`, `o.a_changed?` will be false.

You're using `:counter_cache` but internally, that uses [`update_counters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-update_counters) and that:

> simply does a direct SQL update for the record with the given ID, altering the given hash of counters by the amount given by the corresponding value

So after `update_counters` has been called, the counter attribute will not be marked as *changed* as the counter value in the database will be the new one.

I think you'll have to move your `average_rate` logic into an `after_save` callback on Comment.